# Every polynomial has the same roots as any of its associates.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Every polynomial has the same roots as any of its associates.

For some polynomial $p(x)$, there exists an associate of the form $c\cdot g(x)=p(x)$ where $c$ is some integer. So would I factor $p(x)$ and get $x-c$ as a root and see if it's in $g(x)$? I feel like I know a lot of definitions but do not know how to apply them.

Comment: Hint: what is a root?

Comment: @Ennar If $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $c$ is an element of the field then $p(c)=0$ and $c$ is a root. And $c$ is a root iff $x-c$ is a factor of $p(x)$.

Comment: So, if $\alpha$ is a root of of the polynomials, and $cg(\alpha) = p(\alpha)$...

Comment: Are you multiplying by $c$? And there is no number $d\neq 0$ in your context for which $cd=0$?

Comment: So for $g(x) \cdot c = p(x)$, if the root is $\alpha$ then $p(\alpha)=g(\alpha)*c$ so the root is a mutliple?

Comment: I am not clear what you mean by an associate, and what context you are in. Are your coefficients integers/rational numbers/ real numbers etc. Also is $c$ supposed to be a root as well as a multiplier?

Comment: You should be proving that, ***for all*** polynomials, three exists an associate....  (It's not okay to prove only for "some" polynomials.....)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, the problem is to show that all roots of $f(x)$ are roots of $g(x)$ where $cg(x) = f(x)$ for some constant $c$.  Then suppose $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$.  Then $f(\alpha) = 0$, so $cg(\alpha) = 0$, and $g(\alpha) = 0$.  The converse is very similar, so this gives that $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$ if and only if $\alpha$ is a root of $g(x)$.